# Working SQL yields Syntax Error in pg-promise

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I have the following code in one of my endpoints:

```
    let setText = ''
    for (const [ key, value ] of Object.entries(req.body.info)) {
        setText = setText.concat(`${key} = ${value}, `)
    }
    // Last character always an extra comma and whitespace
    setText = setText.substring(0, setText.length - 2)

    db.one('UPDATE students SET ${setText} WHERE id = ${id} RETURNING *', { setText, id: req.body.id })
        .then(data => {
            res.json({ data })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).json({'error': err.message})
        })
```

It is supposed to dynamically generate the SQL from the request body. When I log the created SQL, it generates correctly. It even works when I directly query the database. However, whenever I run the endpoint, I get a syntax error that's "at or near" whatever `setText` is. I've tried using slice instead of substring with no change.

Comment: Have you tried using console.log in the `then` and `catch` sections to see which/either are triggered?

Comment: You must never concatenate values manually, the way you do, that's a strict no-no with queries. You must use the formatting engine offered by the library.

Comment: @Graham the catch is being triggered because on requests, I get 400 with the error object.

Comment: That would have been very valuable information to see in the question's text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never concatenate values manually, as they are not escaped properly then, and open your code to possible SQL injections.

Use the tools that the library offers. For an `UPDATE` from a dynamic object, see below:

```js
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(req.body.info, {table: 'students'});

const query = pgp.helpers.update(req.body.info, cs) +
                  pgp.as.format(' WHERE id = ${id} RETURNING *', req.body);

db.one(query)
    .then(data => {
        res.json({ data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({error: err.message})
    });
```

Comment: I'm still very new to this library, thanks for your help, I'll give it a shot later.